# Unable to print UDF logs in Aerospike

Tags: lua, aerospike

I am not able to print log in UDF(in Lua) of aerospike.
Logging configuration in conf file of aerospike is:

```
logging {
        console {
                context any info
        }
        file  /var/log/aerospike/aerospike.log {
                context any info
        }
        file /var/log/aerospike/lua.log {
                context any critical
                context aggr debug
                context udf debug
                context query debug
        }
}
```

Source code for logging-

```
function filter(topRec)
  debug("Hello")
  info("Hello")

end
```

Comment: Do you see the record being opened and closed in the lua.log? For example: Jan 31 2018 17:35:54 GMT: DEBUG (udf): (udf_record.c:73) [ENTER] Opening record key:<Digest>:0x6902655800a8e0b15d7837a293ed11f6d7bb4e8a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed my aerospike.conf to your logging stanza, then registered your module and ran it from AQL.

```
$ tail -7 /var/log/aerospike/lua.log 
Jan 31 2018 17:41:57 GMT: DEBUG (udf): (udf_record.c:73) [ENTER] Opening record key:<Digest>:0x6902655800a8e0b15d7837a293ed11f6d7bb4e8a
Jan 31 2018 17:41:57 GMT: DEBUG (udf): (/opt/aerospike/usr/udf/lua/test.lua:43) Hello
Jan 31 2018 17:41:57 GMT: INFO (udf): (/opt/aerospike/usr/udf/lua/test.lua:44) Hello
Jan 31 2018 17:41:57 GMT: DEBUG (udf): (udf_record.c:246) [ENTER] Closing record key:<Digest>:0x6902655800a8e0b15d7837a293ed11f6d7bb4e8a
Jan 31 2018 17:41:57 GMT: DEBUG (udf): (udf_record.c:374) [ENTER] NumUpdates(0) 
Jan 31 2018 17:41:57 GMT: DEBUG (udf): (udf_record.c:246) [ENTER] Closing record key:<Digest>:0x6902655800a8e0b15d7837a293ed11f6d7bb4e8a
Jan 31 2018 17:41:57 GMT: DEBUG (udf): (udf_record.c:374) [ENTER] NumUpdates(0)
```

Which version are you using? Did you check the file permissions for those log files - can your server write to them?

Comment: It was permission issue. Thanks yaar.

Comment: @Ronen - yaar ==> buddy (not forest)  :-)

Comment: I know! But then it's also 'great' in piratese.